# Why can TypeScript only Sometimes Index an Object by a String

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, ts-node

Why can TypeScript index a typed object by string when that string is a constant or a simple string variable, but it's unable to index a typed object by a string if that string is pulled out of an array

That is, consider the following code

```
class Foo {
    public bar: string = 'hello';

    public test() {
        // this works
        console.log(this['bar'])

        // this also works
        const index = 'bar';
        console.log(this[index])

        // in both cases above I have successfully used
        // a string as an index for my type Foo

        // However, this doesn't work
        const props:string[] = ['bar']
        for(const [key,value] of props.entries()) {
            console.log(value); // prints 'bar' to terminal/console
            console.log(this[value])
        }

        // Nor does this
        for(let i=0;i<props.length;i++) {
            console.log(this[props[i]])
        }

        // when looping over an array of string and trying to use the
        // string to index the object, I get the following error
        // why.ts:20:25 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any'
        // type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to
        // index type 'Foo'.
    }
}

const foo = new Foo;
foo.test()


class Foo {
    public bar: string = 'hello';

    public test() {
        // this works
        console.log(this['bar'])

        // this also works
        const index = 'bar';
        console.log(this[index])

        // in both cases above I have successfully used
        // a string as an index for my type Foo

        // However, this doesn't work
        const props:string[] = ['bar']
        for(const [key,value] of props.entries()) {
            console.log(value); // prints 'bar' to terminal/console
            console.log(this[value])
        }

        // Nor does this
        for(let i=0;i<props.length;i++) {
            console.log(this[props[i]])
        }

        // when looping over an array of string and trying to use the
        // string to index the object, I get the following error
        // why.ts:20:25 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any'
        // type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to
        // index type 'Foo'.
    }
}

const foo = new Foo;
foo.test()
```

Both of these work.

```
console.log(this['bar'])
//...
const index = 'bar';
console.log(this[index])
```

TypeScript's able to index my object by a string.

However, the later examples where I'm looping over a string array

```
const props:string[] = ['bar']
for(const [key,value] of props.entries()) {
    console.log(value); // prints 'bar' to terminal/console
    console.log(this[value])
}

for(let i=0;i<props.length;i++) {
    console.log(this[props[i]])
}
```

won't run/compile.  I get the following error.

```
why.ts:42:17 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Foo'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Foo'.

42     console.log(foo[value])
```

So this error message -- *expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Foo'* seems to run counter to my first two examples.

So what's going on here?  Help a poor dynamic language programmer understand what TypeScript is trying to tell me.  Bonus points for a sample that actually allows me to iterate over an array of strings and use one as an object index.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is simple, if typescript can prove the access is safe, the indexing is allowed.

When you write `this['bar']` typescript sees the string literal and it can trivially check that `this` has a property `bar`

When you write `const index = 'bar';` you may think the type of `index` is `string` but it is actually not, the type of `index` is the [string literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) `'bar'`, so typescript will know the only possible value in `index` is `'bar'`. Since `index` can only hold bar, typescript can check that the access `this[index]` is valid by checking `this` has a property `bar`

When you write `const props:string[]` typescript will not make any other inferences about `props` it is an array of `string`. This means when you access `this[prop]` typescript needs to be sure `this` is indexable by any `string`, which since it does not have an index signature, it is not and thus the access throws an error. If you use `as const` to make ts infer literal types for the array instead of `string` and remove the explicit annotation, you will be able to perform the index access:

```
const props = ['bar'] as const
for(const [key,value] of props.entries()) {
    console.log(value); 
    console.log(this[value])//ok
}

for(let i=0;i<props.length;i++) {
    console.log(this[props[i]])
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#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-Zk4OdzkuUg+zAWt9wyAUJkIKx0zJECek4ZstjFYBf3+MCFiWMtqznfYZAuZDrk4ewzD1ONMUOJAOEYXg9DgRBRBopc5FoJRUCAA)

You can also use a type assertion if you are sure `prop` is a key of `this`:

```
const props = ['bar']
for(const [key,value] of props.entries()) {
    console.log(this[value as keyof this])
}
```

Or if you want to get really fancy you can use a custom type guard or custom type assertion, but that seems like overkill here.

Comment: Abandoning my answer so just adding documentation link as a comment: OP might want to read about [string literal types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to read.  I suspect it was due to an inability to infer strings out of the array but hearing it from a clear expert always puts the mind at ease.  Also, I didn't realize you could have actual constant arrays in TypeScript (vs. the variable being const but not its constants), and `keyof this` is sort of breaking my mind right now (in a good way).  That you for helping me get back on my dynamic bulls—t :)

Comment: @ALANSTORM FYI, `keyof` works for any type not just `this`

Comment: Adding link to updated docs URL mentioned by @jcalz - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html